# Is it 'wrong' to make User Controls if it is not for reusability?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I can't decide if it is good or bad to make many user controls. I am only doing it cause I find it easier to work on a control where there are not a lot of components. If something needs to be fixed it is also easier. Kind of like how you split your program up in a lot of classes.

However multiple controls adds a bit more complexity when it comes to passing data around. I guess my question is more if it is normal to create a 'god' class when it comes to GUI programming in winforms.

Almost every video tutorials I see, they only work on one form! While I can use like 5 controls before I have a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reasons to create User Controls in WinForms:**

1. Reuse of functionality.
2. [Encapsulation and data hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).
3. Readability and maintainability.
4. [Single responsibility principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
5. Design-time editor integration for assignable properties.
6. Ability to [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring)/enhance/reuse in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Have you heard about encapsulation and components? It is just your case.

Comment: Ye I have. Just curious if it was different when it comes to GUI programming in C#, since I got the impression I was the only one doing it.

Comment: The common sense applies to GUI as well. Just keep balance between convenience of componentization and inconvenience of passing messages among too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well from a Web Developers perspective -- no, I don't believe so.  In fact I believe in the NerdDinner book for ASP.NET MVC there's a section where the author(s) creates a partial (similar to usercontrol) for the sake of readability purposes.  And these are the top guys at MS who wrote this book.